# Showing and hiding div tags by their ID order using a button

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I made a small questionnaire and I placed each question in a div tag. I'm trying to display the div tags in order, so when the user click the "Next" button it will move on to the next div and hide the previous one. Kind of like a paging system? I thought about creating some sort of a for loop but I feel  like my code is super messy. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
<form>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
<div id="7"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="9"></div>
<div id="10"></div>



 <button type="button">Next</button> 
 <button type="button">Back</button> 
</form>

<script>
visible(){
document.getElementById('1').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('2').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('3').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('4').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('5').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('6').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('7').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('8').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('9').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('10').style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript functions to setup your divs. This uses jQuery for smooth transition as well.

```
<div id="1">Question 1</div>
<div id="2" class="hidden">Question 2</div>
<div id="3" class="hidden">Question 3</div>
<div id="4" class="hidden">Question 4</div>
<div id="5" class="hidden">Question 5</div>
<div id="6" class="hidden">Question 6</div>
<div id="7" class="hidden">Question 7</div>
<div id="8" class="hidden">Question 8</div>
<div id="9" class="hidden">Question 9</div>
<div id="10" class="hidden">Question 10</div>


<button type="button" onclick="reverseDiv();">Back</button>
<button type="button" onclick="advanceDiv();">Next</button> 

<script>
var divNum=1;

advanceDiv = function() {
    if(divNum < 10) {
        divNum++;
        $('#' + (divNum-1)).slideToggle();
        $('#' + divNum).slideToggle();
    }
    else {
        /* last slide reached */
    alert('last question');
    }
}

reverseDiv = function() {
  if(divNum > 1) {
        divNum--;
        $('#' + (divNum+1)).slideToggle();
        $('#' + divNum).slideToggle();
    }
  else {
    alert('first question');
  }
}
</script>
```

Here's a jsfiddle to show functionality (and also includes arrow keys to move between functions): https://jsfiddle.net/79xupebb/1/

Answer (score 1):

To think about the **start** and the **end** in this is case is important.

What happens if you are at the end and then click the next button? Then you have to go to the start. And if you are at the start point and click the previous button, you have to go to the end:

```
if(current === start && direction === "prev") current = end;
if(current === end && direction === "next") current = start;
```

To make all the divs `display: none` and only the first one `display: block` use **CSS**, like:

```
#container div {
    display: none;
}

#container div:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

with **HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1">div1</div>
    <div id="2">div2</div>
    <div id="3">div3</div>
    ...
</div>
```

All togehter with **plain JavaScript**:

```js
var prev = document.getElementById("prev");
var next = document.getElementById("next");

var start = 1;
var end = 10;

var current = 1;

function slide(direction, start, end) {
 document.getElementById(current).style.display = "none";
    
    if(current === start && direction === "prev") {
     current = end;
    } else if(current === end && direction === "next") {
     current = start;
    } else if(direction === "next") {
     current += 1;
    } else if(direction === "prev") {
        current -= 1;
    }
    
    document.getElementById(current).style.display = "block";
}

prev.addEventListener("click", function() {
 slide("prev", start, end);
});

next.addEventListener("click", function() {
 slide("next", start, end);
});
```

```css
#container div {
    display: none;
}

#container div:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="1">div1</div>
    <div id="2">div2</div>
    <div id="3">div3</div>
    <div id="4">div4</div>
    <div id="5">div5</div>
    <div id="6">div6</div>
    <div id="7">div7</div>
    <div id="8">div8</div>
    <div id="9">div9</div>
    <div id="10">div10</div>
    
    <button id="prev" type="button">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do what you want. Use a counter (`current`), start it at `1` and increase it/ decrease it whenever the user clicks one of the buttons, then loop through your `div` list and make them all `display:none` except the one that corresponds to your `current` value.

```js
var current = 1;
function next(){
 current+=1;
 for(var i = 1; i<10; i++){
  document.getElementById(i).style.display = ((current==i)?"block":"none");
 }
}
function back(){
 current-=1;
 for(var i = 1; i<=10; i++){
  document.getElementById(i).style.display = ((current==i)?"block":"none");
 }
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="1" style="display:block">one</div>
<div id="2" style="display:none">two</div>
<div id="3" style="display:none">three</div>
<div id="4" style="display:none">four</div>
<div id="5" style="display:none">five</div>
<div id="6" style="display:none">six</div>
<div id="7" style="display:none">aaaa</div>
<div id="8" style="display:none">bbb</div>
<div id="9" style="display:none">nnn</div>
<div id="10" style="display:none">ggg</div>
<button type="button" onclick="next()">Next</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="back()">Back</button> 
</form>
```

**Note:** My code has no safeguards so it will go below 1 and above 10, you can always check with an `if` statement in each of the buttons' functions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i;
for(i=2;i<=10;i++)
  document.getElementById(''+i).style.display = "none";
i=1; 

document.getElementById('btnNext').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById(''+i).style.display = "none";
  i++;
  document.getElementById(''+i).style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById('btnPrev').onclick = function(){
  document.getElementById(''+i).style.display = "none";
  i--;
  document.getElementById(''+i).style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
<div id="4">4</div>
<div id="5">5</div>
<div id="6">6</div>
<div id="7">7</div>
<div id="8">8</div>
<div id="9">9</div>
<div id="10">10</div>



 <button type="button" id="btnNext">Next</button> 
 <button type="button" id="btnPrev">Back</button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the onclick property to your buttons first:

```
<button type="button" onclick="showNext()">Next</button> 
<button type="button" onclick="showPrev()">Back</button>
```

Then retrieve the divs by adding the `class="quest"` to every div

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("quest");

function showNext(){
for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++){
  if (el[i].style.display == "block"){
  el[i].style.display = "none";
  if ((i+1)==el.length) i=-1;
  el[i+1].style.display = "block";
  break;
  }
}
}

function showPrev(){
for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++){
  if (el[i].style.display == "block"){
  el[i].style.display = "none";
  if (i==0) i=el.length;
  el[i-1].style.display = "block";
  break;
  }
}

}
```